# Adjust size and position of UITextField according to text entered

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have one `UITextField` in my application of width 150 pixels. When user add text, when text size exceeds beyond the width of `textfield`, `textfield` width should be increased accordingly so that the position is same and all text entered is displayed properly. I used following code but no luck.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    float width = [textField.text sizeWithFont:textField.font
                             constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, textField.bounds.size.height)].width;

    if (width  > (textField.frame.size.width +50 )) {

        CGRect rect = textField.frame;
        rect.size.width +=10 ;

        textField.frame =rect;
    }

    return YES ;
}
```

Comment: Hi prerna, did you tried [textView setContentHuggingPriority:NSLayoutPriorityFittingSizeCompression-1.0 forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical];

Comment: It s textfield by the way. I tried but my app crashes with exception unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: what if the text entered is very long? Then it should be in multiline, correct naa?

Comment: No maximum size will be provided .

Comment: then you should make the max width at first and then, make the text centered align, isn't so simple?

Comment: That was a simple trick...Thank you so much. Never thought of that b4. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you say, It will be of fixed length, then you can do in this way:

Set the max width of UITextField, and make the text centered align.